# Slide down transparent CCScene

Tags: game-design, cocos2d-iphone

I want a transparent CCScene (or CCLayer) to slide down when the game is paused...and I want it to be clear enough to see the CCLayer behind it.

How could I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `opacity` property on CCLayer. Any child you have added to that layer will also be affected.

Comment: Where would I put that? In my First layer or the layer I am going to (The sliding transparent layer)?

Comment: @Coder404 The sliding **transparent** layer would be the one you make **transparent**. You would need to add the layer as a child over the layer that all of your game objects are on. You can do this using `addChild:z:`. Might be helpful to dive into the docs a bit deeper.